# Where to keep business logic that changes very often

Tags: java, web-services, e-commerce

I have a requirement where I need to put some logic to calculate the rank of some entity (for example a site user eligible for bonus prize).  This logic changes very often depending upon the sales, available products, season etc. Also, different installations of the application will have different logic to calculate this rank. I am not sure where should I put this logic. If I put it in java I would have to go for frequent deployments. Getting it through webservice too doesn't looks that promising.

I heard Drools can be used in such scenarios but I have never used it in past. Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the classes that implement this logic as decoupled as possible. Use well defined interfaces, and allow each installation to provide it's own implementation if necessary. A Dependency Injection framework, like Spring could be a great help.

Also, consider making your projects in a way that you can deploy independently API and implementation. Maven could help a lot on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can place set of rules in JSON, XML file.
There will be a set of rules.
Your java program will read tags from that file to perform calculations.
For example:

```
<CalculateBonus>
  <minVal>10</minVal>
  <maxVal>30</maxVal>
</CalculateBonus>
```

Then java will read that file containing that rule and get all required data from it:

```
Int nonPremiumDiscount = 10;//got from file
Int premiumDiscount = 30;//got from file
if(person.isPremiumMember)
{
   calculateDiscount(premiumDiscount,price);
}
else
{
   calculateDiscount(nonPremiumDiscount,price);
}
```

If you design your program carefully you will be able to add new rules modify them without or with small change to the code.

That is just idea and would not work for you. But it is exactly what I am doing right now. I have different rules applying to different kind of objects in my code. So for example if I want to validate some additional objects/classes etc (Hope u get what I mean) I just add new rule to my file without even changing a code.

That is really simplified example. In my case I have more than 10 different files having aprox 100 rules each. All of them are in some way connected. So I have rules for general validation but there I include references to other rules in another file:
GeneralValidation -> ValidateEntities -> Something Else

Comment: It sounds logical but what if my formula keeps changing say (a+b)/2 changes to a*b/2 some day or some more parameters are added?

Comment: Put that formula into the rule file and parse it to the method?
I have xpaths in my files and they changes as well I just parse them to my method and get what I want